# pytube - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'filter'

Tags: python, pytube

I have a very simple code using pytube in python:

```
yt = YouTube(video_link)

video = yt.streams.filter(progressive=True, file_extension='mp4').order_by('resolution').desc().first()
```

The following error occurs:

File "C:\dev\projects\python_proj\videodownloader\C001Youtube.py", line 20, in DownloadOneVideo
video = yt.streams.filter(progressive=True, file_extension='mp4').order_by('resolution').desc().first()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'filter'

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the value of `video_link`?

Comment: `yt.streams` is `None`, that's all there is to say.

Comment: the value is video_link is a general youtube video link, below is an example:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ITZUs635tIw

Comment: I had the same problem.I think i deleted pytube and reinstalled it

Comment: No problem with the codes, just that the filter(progressive=True, file_extension='mp4') has resulted in nothing found