# Pytube common error while downloading video PYTHON

Tags: python, pytube

I am trying to download a YouTube video using `pytube` but i get the error bellow, this error has been mentioned in stack overflow many times but almost all of them are outdated.

> [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71898677/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-span-pytube) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68604542/pytube-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-filter)  questions are having the same problems and are left unanswered.

> This question has been answered  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70943978/pytube-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-span) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70060263/pytube-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-span) but the answered appears to be outdated and so it does not work anymore.

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\keibo\PycharmProjects\bot2\Location\main.py", line 60, in <module>
    DownloadVideo(f'{(Main.get("result")[int(choice)]).get("id")}')
  File "C:\Users\keibo\PycharmProjects\bot2\Location\main.py", line 22, in DownloadVideo
    video_stream = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
  File "C:\Users\keibo\PycharmProjects\bot2\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 296, in streams
    return StreamQuery(self.fmt_streams)
  File "C:\Users\keibo\PycharmProjects\bot2\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 181, in fmt_streams
    extract.apply_signature(stream_manifest, self.vid_info, self.js)
  File "C:\Users\keibo\PycharmProjects\bot2\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\extract.py", line 409, in apply_signature
    cipher = Cipher(js=js)
  File "C:\Users\keibo\PycharmProjects\bot2\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 43, in __init__
    self.throttling_plan = get_throttling_plan(js)
  File "C:\Users\keibo\PycharmProjects\bot2\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 411, in get_throttling_plan
    transform_plan_raw = find_object_from_startpoint(raw_code, match.span()[1] - 1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'span'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**Code:**

```
def DownloadVideo(ID):
    yt = YouTube(f'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={ID}')
    video_stream = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
    video_stream.download(output_path='OutPut', filename=f'{ID}.mp4')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'span' when using pytube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75765328/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-span-when-using-pytube)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error might because of a modification in youtube cipher algorithm or something else, you can still try with `pytube` but you will be better with an alternative library like the way more used and updated `yt-dlp` with `pip install yt-dlp`

still you can try to install the last version with `pip install --upgrade pytube`

Comment: I have already tried `pip install --upgrade pytube` but i did not know there is other library that can do this, Thank you.